# SOLVED Laravel website returns "Error 404" for GET requests

Tags: laravel, routes

So I got a template of a Flutter app that retrieves all its data from a website using HTTP get requests.

I have the following method that gets the list of resturaunts:

```
Future<Stream<Restaurant>> getNearRestaurants(LocationData myLocation, LocationData areaLocation) async {
  String _nearParams = '';
  String _orderLimitParam = '';
  if (myLocation != null && areaLocation != null) {
    _orderLimitParam = 'orderBy=area&limit=5';
    _nearParams = '&myLon=${myLocation.longitude}&myLat=${myLocation.latitude}&areaLon=${areaLocation.longitude}&areaLat=${areaLocation.latitude}';
  }
  final String url = '${GlobalConfiguration().getString('api_base_url')}restaurants?$_nearParams&$_orderLimitParam';
  final client = new http.Client();
  final streamedRest = await client.send(http.Request('get', Uri.parse(url)));

  return streamedRest.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(json.decoder).map((data) => Helper.getData(data)).expand((data) => (data as List)).map((data) {
    return Restaurant.fromJSON(data);
  });
}
```

However when I swap the template's url variable for my own website, the app gets stuck and **streamRest** returns with an error 404 page.

**Tried Solutions:**

- I surrounded it with a try/catch block and it gave me no exceptions.
- I also installed postman and checked my website with the GET statement for the same list of restaurants I try to retrieve in the flutter code posted above and see this: [Postman GET screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b84lH.png)
- Its as if my website cannot route to the specific pages in my API folder. But they are all defined in api.php.

**Update 1:**

My web.php looks like this https://pastebin.com/QRG300uL. It seems to be similar to what was suggested below

**Update 2:**

I ran **php artisan route::list** and it showed that all the routes seem to be there:

```
|        | POST      | api/restaurant_reviews                                  | restaurant_reviews.store                 | App\Http\Controllers\API\RestaurantReviewAPIController@store                                   | api                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/restaurant_reviews                                  | restaurant_reviews.index                 | App\Http\Controllers\API\RestaurantReviewAPIController@index                                   | api                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/restaurant_reviews/create                           | restaurant_reviews.create                | App\Http\Controllers\API\RestaurantReviewAPIController@create                                  | api                                                  |
|        | DELETE    | api/restaurant_reviews/{restaurant_review}              | restaurant_reviews.destroy               | App\Http\Controllers\API\RestaurantReviewAPIController@destroy                                 | api                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/restaurant_reviews/{restaurant_review}              | restaurant_reviews.show                  | App\Http\Controllers\API\RestaurantReviewAPIController@show                                    | api                                                  |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/restaurant_reviews/{restaurant_review}              | restaurant_reviews.update                | App\Http\Controllers\API\RestaurantReviewAPIController@update                                  | api                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/restaurant_reviews/{restaurant_review}/edit         | restaurant_reviews.edit                  | App\Http\Controllers\API\RestaurantReviewAPIController@edit                                    | api                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/restaurants                                         | restaurants.index                        | App\Http\Controllers\API\RestaurantAPIController@index                                         | api                                                  |
|        | POST      | api/restaurants                                         | restaurants.store                        | App\Http\Controllers\API\RestaurantAPIController@store                                         | api                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/restaurants/create                                  | restaurants.create                       | App\Http\Controllers\API\RestaurantAPIController@create                                        | api                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/restaurants/{restaurant}                            | restaurants.show                         | App\Http\Controllers\API\RestaurantAPIController@show                                          | api                                                  |
|        | DELETE    | api/restaurants/{restaurant}                            | restaurants.destroy                      | App\Http\Controllers\API\RestaurantAPIController@destroy                                       | api                                                  |
|        | PUT|PATCH | api/restaurants/{restaurant}                            | restaurants.update                       | App\Http\Controllers\API\RestaurantAPIController@update                                        | api                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/restaurants/{restaurant}/edit                       | restaurants.edit                         | App\Http\Controllers\API\RestaurantAPIController@edit                                          | api                                                  |
|        | POST      | api/send_reset_link_email                               |                                          | App\Http\Controllers\API\UserAPIController@sendResetLinkEmail                                  | api                                                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/settings                                            |                                          | App\Http\Controllers\API\UserAPIController@settings                                            | api                                                  |
```

**Solution:**

This worked for me after changing alot of things, I changed my GET request url from "www.domain.com/api/resturants" to "www.domain.com/public/api/resturants"

Comment: can you run a php artisan route:list and post the output here?

Comment: @FellipeSanches Posted (Update 2)

Comment: Is Laravel in production? No route is working for me, and this could be a problem with the web server, Apache / Ngix too...

Comment: I had no idea that you had so many routes, and that the API already seemed to be ready. Please delete the link with all routes, leaving it exposed is a security risk.

Comment: in short, I recommend putting the routes to work with POSTMAN, only after that to go to the flutter.

Comment: I'm just testing it with postman right now. Not touching flutter just messing with laravel and the apache server but I hit a brick wall with this. It just gives me an error 404 as if the page just does not exist.

Comment: The website works fine EXCEPT for the API part of it. Is there a chance the route cannot handle the API controllers being inside a subfolder within the Controller folder?

Comment: create a very simple route like:
Route::get('/test', function () { return 'ok'; });
And check...

Comment: Your Postman screenshot shows you accessing the `/api/restaurants` route.  The routes file you linked to does not include any `/api` routes. `it showed that all the routes seem to be there` - you haven't shown us that. The simplest solution, which has not yet been ruled out, is that you have no `/api/restaurants` route configured.  If you do, show us that - here, not on an external site, and just copy-paste the relevant lines, not everything. Copy-paste the **relevant** few lines of output of `php artisan route:list`, here, as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Updated to show the appropriate route information

Comment: @FellipeSanches I added "Route::get('test', function () { return 'ok'; });" to my api.php and postman still returns a Error 404. Am I missing something?

Comment: in /config/app.php turn on Application Debug Mode, to have more information about what happens

Comment: @FellipeSanches It is already on, where do I find where it prints the information though? In laravel.log? Also I added the test route to my api.php and web.php and my route:list updated to show this  "|| GET|HEAD  | test | Closure| ". However postman still returns error 404 on www.goceries.org/test

Comment: The solution you've posted means Laravel is not correctly installed/configured, and **insecure!!** The web server document root should be your `/public` dir, if it is the directory above (as yours is) all your code and `.env` data (usernames, passwords, Stripe keys, etc) are open to the world.

Comment: Wait but my understanding was that with laravel the main index.php had to be in the /html/public folder. So my root server directory is /var/www/html that contains the .env and storage and route folders etc. And then the /var/www/html/public contains the main index.php, .htaccess, etc.

Comment: [No](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know about your flutter code for i use different methods in retrieving data from api but about the routes i suggest you do like me

in web.php the route file

```
//Api routes
Route::get('/company/api/fetch', 'ApiController@fetch_companies');
```

my api controller

```
public function fetch_companies()
{
    $companies = Companies::all();

    return response()->json($companies);
}
```

this way you will get the data passed to the route /company/api/fetch (you can modify that as you want) and when a get request enter this page it will return *json*

and for the request handling in *flutter* side i suggest you make your functions and classes as it is in the [documentations](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

Note: that the flutter solution that i suggested may not work with your case for you are using **Stream** which is different than this type of requests because this type runs only ones while the Stream runs many times and gets data every time it gets new data from the server